# AngularJS Page/View Slider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Basically, what I need to do is create a Fullscreen window display for a shop using data that is being used on their current website, now, I have choosen to use AngularJS for this project, mainly because I want to learn it and the best way to learn is doing.

I have a JSON file containing an array of items, it currently contains the following data:

```
   {
        "prop_id"       : "",
        "prop_title"    : "",
        "prop_postcode" : "",
        "prop_price"    : "",
        "prop_image"    : "",
        "prop_desc"     : "",
        "template"      : "views/prop-no-thumbs.html",
        "info_image"    : "",
        "duration"      : "4000"

    },
```

So, I have a unique ID, the template that I wish to use to display this item and the duration I want the view to be present on the screen. These will vary.

What would be the best way to handle this in AngularJS, I have made a start using some example code I found on GitHub but can't seem to get it to automatically rotate (question can viewed here: [AngularJS: Slide divs automatically with a set duration on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128041/angularjs-slide-divs-automatically-with-a-set-duration-on-page-load) ).

Any ideas? Should I also be using a third party plugin? Does anyone have any tutorials or resources to handle something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [angular ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) carousel directive and tweak with css (remove the arrows, resize it, etc...)

Comment: This would work great but not what I need, as it will load all the views onto the same page, there could be hundreds, so dont want to overload the page.

Comment: You could solve this by "lazy loading" the slides. Inside each slide will be an ng-include. You could provide the src attribute only for the active slide, the previously active slide and the next slide.

Comment: thinking about a 'larger' example (html5 powerpoint presentation type of thing); this is more useful http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation. The one in the bootsrap example is just about toggling visible stuff